# JavaScript function making CSS :hover not function correctly

Tags: javascript, css

**Text color wont change on hover once function is used.**

I have the following `<div>`:

```
<div class="test" id="test_id" onClick="tempFunc()">HELLO</div>
```

CSS for the above line:

```
.test {     
    font-family: 'CenturyGothicRegular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    color: white;
}

.test:hover {   
    color: orange;  
}
```

Above all works as expected.

Color of text starts as white, hover changes to orange. When clicked, it opens tempFunc().  In that function this line is passed:

```
function tempFunc() {   
   document.getElementById('test_id').style.color = "orange";
}
```

That will change the color to orange fine. When user clicks another button:

```
<div class= home" id="home_id" onClick="homeFunc()">CLOSE</div>

function homeFunc() {   
   document.getElementById('test_id').style.color = "white";
}
```

**Problem** - After that happens the CSS **test:hover** is completely ignored.  Nothing happens when hovering over "HELLO", color remains white.

Comment: Have you tried setting `.style.color = "";` to remove the inline style and default back to what's in the stylesheet? (As compared to explicitly setting inline `.style.color = "white";`, which overrides the stylesheet?)

Comment: see [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I think may be this css is  override from another

Comment: I have not tried that, but I will now.

Comment: What is `type="button"` for a div

Comment: I don't need that, you are correct.  I see the problem is Javascript overrides CSS

Comment: no, it does not. inline style has a higher specificity than any css selector - which, in your case you are adding the inline style through javascript, but it's not javascript that is the problem

Comment: I am still stumped on this.  I am trying to use addClass, still no luck